# Two segment Host one physical server GreenPlum

Tags: host, greenplum, segment

I have one server with two physical disk's, could I install two segment host each one in the separate disk, which means install segment host in the first disk, and another one in the second disk? and if yes, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When init GPDB, you specify the data directories for the segments. Mount each disk on a different mount point, and specify the mount points (or subdirectories) as data dirs.

Additional question: you do have a backup of the database, in case one of the disk fails, right?

Comment: i am planning to enable segment mirror features , in order to backup the data , is there any other way?

Comment: How useful is mirroring, if your single physical server is down?

Comment: i have multi physical servers , i will  do the mirroring for each single disk to other one in other physical server , is this helpful

Comment: Ok, that works, it's just not what you specified in your initial question.

Comment: What other questions do you have? If it fits this question, please update your question. Or open another one. Likely the answers to your questions will be interesting for more people. Also there is a Greenplum mailing list.

Comment: my question , is there any installation should be done on segment host , or only in master node , and i am using ubuntu OS , is it compatible with greenplum??

Comment: i read it , but actually i cant determine is there is any installation should be run on segment host or not

Comment: That is also covered in the installation guide. First install the software on all segments, exchange ssh keys, add all hosts to the database while init it.

Comment: can you please share the document that covered installation on Ubuntu OS

Comment: can you please add me on skype rami.soudi gmail

Comment: Sorry, I'm not your personal support account. Please open a support request with one of the companies providing support for GPDB. Or post to the users mailing list.